# AppEngine error 400 when requesting access token

Tags: delphi, google-app-engine, oauth, indy

I'm writing a Delphi based PC application which accesses an AppEngine servlet. I'm trying to use the OAuth 1.0 dance to authenticate users and allow access to a restricted part of the application.
I'm able to get access to the restricted servlet using a browser and going through google user authentication.
I'm now trying to implement the dance.
I successfully get the token and token secret using OAuthGetRequestToken.

```
Key := 'XXXX.appspot.com';
Secret := 'YYYY';
URL := 'https://XXXX.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken';
Consumer := TOAuthConsumer.Create(Key, Secret);
HMAC := TOAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1.Create;
ARequest := TOAuthRequest.Create(URL);
ARequest := ARequest.FromConsumerAndToken(Consumer, nil, URL,'','oob','');
ARequest.Sign_Request(HMAC, Consumer, nil,true);
URL := URL + '?' + ARequest.GetString;
idHTTP1.Get(URL,ms);
ARequest.Destroy;
HMAC.Destroy;
Consumer.Destroy;
```

The GET request and response look like this:

```
GET /_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXX.appspot.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="1511ec6d98e5b89c561b1af4b3022476", oauth_timestamp="1347534557", oauth_consumer_key="XXXX.appspot.com", oauth_callback="oob", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="JPSgMsipsLumldKsca8SA8gDXgw%3D"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2012 11:09:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 88
oauth_token=4%2FY4ReEZt9v8IYHJ_4WnZYkzurXOgw&oauth_token_secret=S9150fuyvo_jjr43Cd47CPzY
```

Next, I authorize the token.

```
URL := 'https://inksureauth.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token='+TOAuthUtil.urlEncodeRFC3986(Token.Text);
IdHTTP1.Get(URL,ms);
```

I'm redirected to the google web page for login. As I stated 'oob' for callback, I receive a verification code on the web page which I copy.

Finally, I try to get exchange the token for an access token. Here I fail.

```
URL := 'https://XXXX.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken';
Key := 'XXXX.appspot.com';
Secret := 'YYYY';
Consumer := TOAuthConsumer.Create(Key, Secret);
ARequest := TOAuthRequest.Create(URL);
AToken := TOAuthToken.Create(TOAuthUtil.urlEncodeRFC3986(Token.Text), TokenSecret.Text);
ARequest.HTTPURL := URL;
ARequest := ARequest.FromConsumerAndToken(Consumer,AToken , URL,'','','VERIFICATION CODE FROM WEB PAGE');
HMAC := TOAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1.Create;
ARequest.Sign_Request(HMAC, Consumer, AToken,true);
URL := URL + '?' + ARequest.GetString;
IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
IdHTTP1.Get(URL,ms);
HMAC.Destroy;
ARequest.Destroy;
Consumer.Destroy;
```

The GET command looks like this:

```
GET /_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=4A86BEECE494C25AF94882F74DEE6231&oauth_timestamp=1347545383&oauth_consumer_key=XXXX.appspot.com&oauth_verifier=yGEhCENYOlni2ayo8aNckyPG&oauth_token=4%2FEKGFo9i2wmuMGcBLmbmQhqDba0z4&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=2ZwRvGp8LnXenTXrjYo5%2FtFHW30%3D HTTP/1.1
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2012 14:09:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 273


<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Bad Request</h1>
<h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I used the OAuth playground to access the same application and it is successful in retrieving the access key. I compared the playground's request parameters to the parameters generated by my application and they are compatible. I used my signing function to sign a request generated by the playground and the signatures matched. What other reason can there be for the last step to fail? 
Is it possible to get a more informative response from the authentication server beyond "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request"?

Update: I have used my application to retrieve an access token to Google calendar successfuly. Using the same code I change back to the AppEngine application and fail on the GetAccessToken step.

Answer (score 0):

Google moved to Oauth 2.0 meanwhile. You can find OAuth 2.0 client authentication solution here:

https://github.com/lordcrc/IndySASLOAuth2

> Simple OAuth2 SASL authenticator for Indy.
>
> Uses the Delphi REST client libraries.
>
> Tested on Delphi XE6.
>
> Licensed under the Apache 2.0 license