# Using Delphi to send email by web service (without leaking credentials and without user interaction)

Tags: web-services, delphi, email

I have a Delphi application, that needs to send a generated PDF file by email to one recepient of a predefined list of recepients.

- I do not want to mess around with MAPI (not all customers have configured this)
- I do not want my customers to enter their mail account details (this means SMTP is no option either)

Therefore I consider to use / setup a PAAS web service to receive the email text, the pdf file and the index number of the recepient to actually do the work.
My question is: Does an out-of-the-box solution exist to do this in Delphi, or what would be a preferable way?

For instance I considered using [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) but there seems to be [no builtin support in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408798/appengine-error-400-when-requesting-access-token). I would prefer an out of the box solution or a tested solution with decent documentation. The server part should be as simple as possible.

**Edited:** Some clarifications:

- The resulting exe is installed at the customer computer. I think setting up an extra mail account therefore is no option, because someone could extract the credentials from the exe and abuse the mail account. The same seems to be true for web services that provide only one (login/password) access.
- Using OAuth2 seems to be no option either because I do want to send the email without user interaction.
- If credentials need to be saved in the executable, and the existing answers suggest so, they should at least provide only very limited rights.

Is this solveable at all?

Comment: Your link does not support your claim that Google App Engine doesn't support Delphi. It only says that one person couldn't get OAuth to work from a Delphi app, and nobody else has any suggestions. GAE indeed doesn't *run* Delphi programs, but you'd be hard-pressed to find *any* app-hosting service that does. Your request for a hosting service or a ready-made app is off-topic at Stack Overflow. If you intend to solve this yourself, your question is too broad; which *part* of the task of doing it yourself are you having trouble with?

Comment: @RobKennedy I did not try to ask for a service or for an ready-made app. I tried to ask for a way to achieve sending an email from a Delphi app without leaking credentials, preferably using Delphi components. Maybe my question is not clear enough?

Comment: @RobKennedy Concerning Delphi components for accessing GAE: I could not find any info that this is built-in in newer Delphi versions - do you know otherwise? My link is no proove, of course, only an indication.

Comment: How can your application know the `the index number of the recepient`, is it a static list so all email recipient index values are hard-coded in the executable?

Comment: @mjn In this special case, yes: it is a static list hard-coded in the executable.

Comment: Regarding OAuth2: this could be a starting point: https://github.com/lordcrc/IndySASLOAuth2

Answer (score 1):

`Is this solveable at all?`

No.

If you require that neither the user (by filling in a login form, as is the case with OAuth 2.0) nor the program (by providing hard-coded credentials) authenticates with the web service, the communication with the web service can not be secure.

I suggest to re-think the security requirements and make them much clearer in your question.

Comment: I need to protect against abuse of the email account. This means the credentials to send the email (which might be hardcoded in the binary) must be different from the ones to administrate the account. Together with the restriction of a fixed list of receipients this should provide the needed security: An attacker could theoretically use the hardcoded account to send emails to the predefined receipients, but could not hijack this for spamming.

Comment: @AloisHeimer attackers could use the hardcoded credentials to `mail-bomb` the predefined recipients with (potentially harmful) PDF attachments

Comment: Hmm, this is true. I could make this harder by requiring a code which matches to the CRC of the PDF. But this would need to be implemented in the exe and thus be circumventable by reverse engineering as well....No perfect solution - how depressing :).

Answer (score 0):

To send mail you can use a webservice like http://www.mailgun.com/ or http://aws.amazon.com/ses/
They provide you with a http(s)-api that you can use to send email messages.

Comment: The Mailgun API and the AWS Query API would require to include secret access keys in the application, which could be extracted by malicious users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Engine with some programming in Python, PHP, Go or Java:

- define a HTTPS address where your GAE application listens for POST requests
- POST the PDF and the Email text with TIdHTTP
- receive the PDF amd theEmail text in the GAE HTTPS server and forward it to the recipient

[Here is an excerpt of a Python example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) for Google App Engine which handles a POST request

```
class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
        self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')
```

Regarding OAuth: GAE supports OAuth but it is not *required*.

Comment: I thought I would need OAuth, if I do not want to hard-code the credentials in the executable?

Comment: @AloisHeimer in this case you need OAuth 2.0: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 - and so you need a OAuth 2.0 library for Delphi (maybe you should update your question and include your minimum security requirements)

Comment: I looked into AOuth 2.0: But I think this would require user interaction to provide the user account details. This is not what I want either. I want to send the email without user interaction and without the possibility to abuse my mail account. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @AloisHeimer it is virtually *impossible* to authenticate without user interaction and without providing hard-coded credentials (in the program or configuration files)